# Affine function is a diffeomorphism?

Tags: diffeomorphism

Given an affine function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ by $$f(x)=T(x)+a$$ such that $T$ is an invertible *Linear map* and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$, is $f$ a *diffeomorphism*?

Comment: what if $T$ is the zero transformation?

Comment: @guy3141 $T$ is invertible, I forgot to mention this fact and added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a diffeomorphism iff $T$ is invertible.
It is easy to see that $f$ is invertible iff $T$ is invertible with inverse
$$f^{-1}(x) = T^{-1}(x - a).$$

As $T^{-1}$ is a linear transformation, it is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Hello and thanks! I forgot to mention that $T$ is invertible, added to the oroginal post.

Comment: No worries, I belive my answer still answers your question regardless?

Comment: A function $g$ is diffeomorphism if it is a bijection, differentiable and $g^{-1}$ is also differentiable. So by your answer the function $f$ is a diffeomorphism, right?

Comment: Yep! That is what I've written as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Another thing I want to ask - Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map and $Q\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a Rectangle. The image $T(Q)$ is also a Rectangle?

Comment: You mean $Q \subset \Bbb R^n$. And no, even in the case that $T$ is invertible, you can have something skewed. Consider $n = 2$ and the map $(x, y) \mapsto (x, x + y)$. The rectangle $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ gets mapped to a parallelogram. (I'm taking the definition of a rectangle to be a set of the form $[a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$).

Comment: Aha! I should have thought about it, thank again